# Updated to Android Studio Arctic Fox - Apply Changes is much, much slower

Tags: android, gradle

I have just upgraded to Android Android Studio Arctic Fox on Mac, and after spending some time reconfiguring everything, I have been able to make my current app working inside the emulator. Now that I am working thought, I realize that the "Apply Changes and Restart Activity" command is extremely slow. Every time I invoke it, Gradle is building and takes up to two minutes to finish and apply the changes. That's ridiculous and happens even if I change just a line of code. Never happened before, the same command used to take a few seconds!

Any ideas? Is there anything I need to set or change to make that work fast as before?

Comment: Run a gradle scan to see what is missing. If you get some errors please post them

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did the scan and got no errors, just warnings: https://justpaste.it/8juat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the way, I did some more research and saw that there are 2 known problems that you could have. However, there is also a solution to this. Take a look at [this page](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/04/android-studio-arctic-fox-canary-15.html) with all known issues.

Possible problem 1:

> The Android Emulator only works with API 30 and API S Developer
> Preview emulator system images.

Possible problem 2:

> The incremental update patcher does not work in Canary 15. Meaning to
> move to the next preview version, you will need to download a fresh
> new copy. The update should be fixed in future releases.

In your case I would [reinstall the update](https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/install/2020.3.1.22/android-studio-2020.3.1.22-mac.dmg) or otherwise check try an older version from the list [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive). If that doesn't work there is no other way then install Android Studio from scratch.

Hope it helped a bit, Good luck! :)

Comment: Yes, thank you! Option two worked. I first installed the version you suggested, and the problem was still there. Then I went on the older version list link you suggested and chose the last one again (July 28th version) and now it works just fine. Appreciated your help!

Comment: Thanks, after update to Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 10 it works better